# Problem with proof of the upper hemicontinuity of correspondence

Tags: real-analysis, game-theory, fixed-point-theorems

I have a problem with a proof I found [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-254-game-theory-with-engineering-applications-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_254S10_lec05.pdf) of the upper hemicontinuity of the *best-reply correspondence* in the Nash Theorem.

Below there is the proof, and here my problems:

**Problems:**

1. Is here implicitly assumed, without loss of generality, that the **utility function** $u_i$ is **increasing in the convergence**? *Otherwise, I don't see how the red inequality stands*.
2. How does the blue inequality stands?
   *Is it related to the implicit assumption that I think we have?*

> **Proposition:** Let $B_i : \Sigma_{-i} \rightrightarrows \Sigma_i$, defined as $$B_i (\sigma_{-i}) := \arg \max_{x \in \Sigma_{i}} u_i (x , \sigma_{-i}) ,$$ 
>   with $B := \prod_{i \in I} B_{i}$. Then, $B$ is upper hemicontinuous.
>
> *[Notice that $\Sigma := \Sigma_{i} \times \Sigma_{-i}$ is nonempty compact convex, and the proof relies on the equivalence of upper hemicontinuity to closedness in this context.]*
>
> ***Proof:***
>   By contradiction, assume that $r$ is not closed. Hence, there exists a sequence $(\sigma^n , \hat{\sigma}^n) \to (\sigma , \hat{\sigma})$ with $\hat{\sigma}^n \in B ( \sigma^n)$, but $\hat{\sigma} \notin B ( \sigma)$. If $\hat{\sigma} \notin B ( \sigma)$, then there is some $i \in N$ such that $\hat{\sigma}_i \notin B_i (\sigma)$. Thus, 
>   there is a $\sigma^{\prime}_i $ such that $u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma_{-i} ) > u_i (\hat{\sigma}_i , \sigma_{-i} ) + 3\varepsilon$.
>
> From the continuity of $u_i$ and the fact that $\sigma_{-i}^n \to \sigma_{-i}$, for $n$ sufficiently large, we have
>
> $$  \color{red}{u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma^{n}_{-i} ) \geq u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma_{-i} ) - \varepsilon .}$$
>
> Bringing those inequalities together we have
>
> $$\color{blue}{u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma^{n}_{-i} ) > %
> u_i ( \hat{\sigma}_i , \sigma_{-i} ) + 2 \varepsilon \geq%
> u_i ( \hat{\sigma}^{n}_i , \sigma^{n}_{-i} ) + \varepsilon ,}$$
>
> where the second inequality comes from the continuity of $u_i$. Hence, this contradicts the assumption that $\hat{\sigma}^{n}_i \in B_{i} ( \sigma^{n}_{-i} )$.

As always, any feedback is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from continuity of the (mixed extensions of the) payoff functions alone alone. Since $u_i$ is continuous, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma^{n}_{-i}=\sigma_{-i}$ implies
$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma^{n}_{-i} )=u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma_{-i} )$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. By the definition of convergence,
$$u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma^{n}_{-i} )\in \big(u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma_{-i} )-\varepsilon,u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma_{-i} )+\varepsilon\big)$$
for $n$ large enough. For such $n$, we therefore have have  $$u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma^{n}_{-i} ) > u_i (\sigma^{\prime}_i , \sigma_{-i} ) - \varepsilon,$$ which proves the red inequality.

A similar argument works for the second blue inequality. Note that there are two blue inequalities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extremely clear answer!